# What is the .net regex to find text between '$' and '<'?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find the regex pattern to find the text  between a string and a char and replace spaces in the text with _.

Example. `< Node Type="Text">Event Log < /Node >`

Expected output : `Event_Log`

Thanks in advance. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote correct desired output?

Comment: To clarify Marco's comment: your example suggests all of the prefix $ should be included while the suffix < should be excluded. This doesn't match your requirements specification. Is this correct?

Comment: You say "without $" but in expected output you have $$$ included...?

Comment: we reject your desired output and put in it's place `Hello World`

Comment: What is the desired output if the input is "... text $$$ Hello $ World </stop>"? Should that "internal" $ be treated as a boundary or as content?

Comment: If you're trying to **use regex to parse [X]HTML** than read this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/449906) first.

Comment: You completely changed your question, too bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        string s = "here is my text $$$ Hello World </stop>";
        Match m = Regex.Match(s, "(\\$[^<]*)<");
        if (m.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "$$$ Hello World </stop>";
string sPattern = "[\\$]{3}([\\d\\s\\w]*)</stop>";

Match m = Regex.Match(str, sPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (m.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1));
}
```

Converted from VB code and not tested after but should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the example is correct and the text of your question wrong, you need:

```
\$+[^$<]*(?=<)
```

If it's the other way around, try this:

```
(?<=\$+)[^$<]*<
```

BTW, all questions like this can be more easily answered using a tool like this [online regex tester](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx).